# 18c Conforming to current password necessary complexity to renew expiring password with the same one

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle18c

After having migrated the database from 11g to 18g (cloud version) I get the message that users password will expire in a few days. Because those users are connection source to many web applications. I would need to reuse the same password.

I tried alter the password duration to unlimited but it is too late for the users already in "grace" status.

So when trying to change their password with the same as the older one; I get the message that they don't match the necessary complexity (either as 2 special characters or capital letters)

```
    ORA-20000: password must contain 2 or more special characters
    28003. 00000 -  "password verification for the specified password failed"
    *Cause:    The new password did not meet the necessary complexity
               specifications and the password_verify_function failed
    *Action:   Enter a different password. Contact the DBA to know the rules for
               choosing the new password
```

Is there a possibility to change the complexity parameters; and if so, is it also toolate for password in "grace" mode ?

Thank you very much for your help

Have a nice day

Comment: You might get a better response on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly create your own password complexity function to do what you want, then associate it with a profile.  I'd suggest also creating a new profile for this, so that you can leave the 'default' alone.  Then assign the new profile to the user(s) in question.